# Typing annotations compatibility comparison without object instances

Tags: python, annotations, typing

I have annotations from `typing`, but no instances. I need perform dynamic analysis (without object instance), that an output typing *annotation* is compatible with an input *annotation*.

Examples below:

```py
from typing import *

# Output -> Input
List[str] -> List[Union[str, int]]  # ok
List[int] -> List[str]  # not ok
Dict[str, str] -> Dict[str, Any]  # ok
Dict[str, List[int]] -> Dict[str, List[Union[float, int]]]  # ok
Dict[str, List[int]] -> Dict[str, List[str]]]  # not ok
List[str] -> Iterator[str]  # ok
```

I have looked into `typeguard`, however, it requires a presence of an instance. In my case, I don't have an instance yet created.

Here is an *abstract* example how this is used. An output is created by `Class1`, then it is used by the `Class2` as an input.

```py
from typing import *

class Class1:
    output: List[str]

class Class2:
    input: List[Union[str, bytes]]
```

The aim here is to check that an output produced by `Class1` can be consumed by `Class2` input. Each class has the annotations under `object.__annotations__`, so we have access to them.

Do you have any suggestions or better ideas how to achieve this without running into an if/else nested hell? Many thanks.

Comment: Classes do not 'use inputs', functions do. That aside, the input-output flow you are describing in text is nowhere to be found in the code example.

Answer (score -1):

Use [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/)

Assuming `file.py` with contents:

```
from typing import List, Union


def f(xs) -> List[int]:
    ...


def g(xs: List[Union[str, int]]) -> List[int]:
    ...


def h(xs: List[str]) -> List[str]:
    ...


a = g(f(...))
b = h(f(...))
```

and running `mypy file.py`, we get:

```
file.py:16: error: Argument 1 to "g" has incompatible type "List[int]"; expected "List[Union[str, int]]"
lpheno/blah.py:16: note: "List" is invariant -- see https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#variance
lpheno/blah.py:16: note: Consider using "Sequence" instead, which is covariant
lpheno/blah.py:17: error: Argument 1 to "h" has incompatible type "List[int]"; expected "List[str]"
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not really helping me. Let me expand a bit further on my question with more examples.

Comment: I would argue otherwise. mypy does really look as what you're looking for

Comment: The mistake I made in my description was that I need dynamic checking, and not static as I said earlier. I used mypy before, I know it does type checking but for static code analysis. I need a way to invoke its functionality programatically. The size of the lib could have a fair amount of overhead is my worry.

Comment: I would suggest you edit your question to actually reflect your usecase then.